# Export multiple chart in a single page using canvas.js

Tags: javascript, canvas, charts

I started using canvas.js recently only and I am trying to create a page with multiple charts, so I followed try out this example first. https://canvasjs.com/samples/dashboards/annual-sales/

So now I want to be able to get the image of the charts 1 by 1 and while doing that I encountered an error called, `Uncaught TypeError: productsRevenuePieChart.exportChart2 is not a function`. For the first chart I was able to export it but when I try doing it for the second chart this error appear. Can someone help me in this? Thanks a lot

The exporting part is the one giving the error:

```
//chart data information

        productsRevenuePieChart.render();
        document.getElementById("exportChart2").addEventListener("click",function(){
      productsRevenuePieChart.exportChart2({format: "jpg"});
    });  

 //more chart data information, this part works
   ordersSplineChart.render();
    document.getElementById("exportChart").addEventListener("click",function(){
  ordersSplineChart.exportChart({format: "jpg"});
});  

//button used
  <button id="exportChart2">Export Chart</button>
  <button id="exportChart">Export Chart</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no exportChart2 method in CanvasJS https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/methods/chart/export-chart/.  By the looks of it, you just need to remove 2 from exportChart2().

Comment: Oh my god you are right thank you so much for your help, was learning this halfway and I thought that was a name that why I added a 2 behind.